# Issue in deploying to IIS

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, iis, deploying

I am facing issues in deploying to IIS. Spent a lot of time googling around and trying out things, Inspecting/Installing features on control panel, and many more things.

Step1> On Visual Studio
I am publishing my app to a physical path,

Step2> On IIS, I am adding a website where I'm pointing to that path, and completing other fields. I also set port 8080 for this since 80 was used by other ones.

Now on clicking browse under manage application in IIS, I am getting localhost:8080/Error (Its stuck in the page, showing nothing). Adding the screenshot here.

[localhost:8080/Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRrO0.png)

Honestly reaching out for help

Comment: Set the start page of the site in Default Document of IIS,

Comment: Can you explain in more details.

Comment: In IIS, Select your project. Then in right hand side you can see some menus. From there select Default Documents and add your start page name.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error In Control Panel --> Programs --> Programs And Features --> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content, IIS Management Console, and HTTP Errors.

[image]

Also, make sure .NET Extensibility 3.5 and .NET Extensibility 4.5 are checked.

[image]

if the issue still exists then open iis. select site and select error pages->select edit feature setting->select detail error message for the local request and custom error pages for remote request.

are you trying to use the asp.net custom error pages?